# Хорошая характеристика

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, как правильно (а может, ни так и ни так).

**Имею** хорошую характеристику или **имеется**?

Answer (score 1):

Если это **деловое письмо**, то лучше написать так: **имею/могу предоставить положительную характеристику с предыдущего места работы.**

***Хорошая характеристика*** ― нейтральный стиль, это выражение применяется, но  в других речевых ситуациях, например:

Одним словом, Лаврентьев дал ему очень **хорошую характеристику**, и это меня успокоило.

Григорий Абрамович при мне на одном из заседаний написал мне **хорошую характеристику** и дал мне ее прочесть.

***Положительная характеристика*** подходит для любого стиля:

Партийная организация Московской государственной филармонии также нашла возможным выдать Тумановскому **положительную** характеристику.

Получив **положительную** характеристику в ведомстве Риббентропа, был направлен на работу в Румынию.

Такую мне за пять минут нашлепала секретарша Галоганова, а проректор приложил к справке **положительную** характеристику.

Answer (score 0):

**Имею хорошую характеристику.

Имеется хорошая характеристика.**

Не видя контекста, можно лишь сказать, что теоретически оба варианта допустимы, хотя и звучат просторечиво. Но каждый из них или оба сразу могут стать неприемлемыми в определенном контексте.

"Имеется характеристика" - канцеляризм (*В деле имеется характеристика с места работы*).

В этом примере кто-то "имел хорошие характеристики":

> Два месяца муж работал и лечился при предприятии, **имел хорошие характеристики**, и все-таки его решили уволить. [Бутылка в доме // «Работница», 1988]